# Multiplicatively written and non-abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

When we write a proof for a multiplicatively written group does this hold true for non-abelian groups?

I mean in general, when we write a proof for a multiplicatively written group, since in my notes, it will hold true for all groups no matter the group operation. But then there are some proofs later on that says it is not true for non-abelian groups, is this not contradicting the proof for the multiplicatively written group (and the notation of multiplicatively written groups) since it doesn't hold for all groups?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the theorem where such a proof appears? It would be helpful to understand better your problem.

Comment: Strictly speaking, notations have nothing to do with properties. Writing your proof using $a \cdot b$ or $a \ast b$ (or something else) doesn't really matter. The important thing is to know what properties (e.g. commutativity) you use in your proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need to understand is that there's no fundamental difference between a group being written additively or multiplicatively. Of course, we tend to use additive for abelian and multiplicative in general, but if you have a theorem that's true for abelian groups then it's true for the multiplicatively written version, it just means your "multiplication" is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

I would go back and re-read whatever it is you're referencing. Or maybe post it here. It sounds like you're confusing separate concepts.