# Is the difference between additive groups and multiplicative groups just a matter of notation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

Groups are sometimes written additively, like $(G,+)$, and sometimes they are written multiplicatively, like $(G,\times)$. But is there really a difference? Is it all just a matter of notation, nothing more? If it is something beyond notation, what is the difference, exactly?

Comment: There is a difference for, say, a field $(K,+,\cdot)$. The multiplicative group $(K^{\times},\cdot)$ is different from the additive group $(K,+)$.

Comment: A group is a set $G$ equipped with a function having domain $G \times G$ and codomain $G$ (i.e. equipped with a binary operation) such that certain axioms are satisfied. The symbols that you use to denote that function are not relevant --- although choosing the notation well certainly makes it easier to communicate the definition other human beings, in particular it makes it easier to write the axioms down.

Comment: (A) When we say Additive group , we can say $a+a=2a$ & $a+a+a=3a$. When we say Multiplicative group , we can say $a \cdot a=a^2$ & $a \cdot a \cdot a=a^3$. (B) Additive group has Identity $0$. Multiplicative group has Identity $1$. (C) Inverses are $-a$ & $a^{-1}$ **(D) These are Notational Shortcuts. (E) Discussions should say which "type" we are considering , when we use such Notational Shortcuts !**

Comment: @LeeMosher: It's interesting, because I suspect that most students won't have any trouble with an instructor renaming a function $f$ to $g$, but going from additive to multiplicative notation leads to questions like this one. Perhaps this reflects that people have a different mental image for binary operations compared to general functions, and don't conceptualise them in the same way. I don't know.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1654427/10513

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's just notation.  Typically, though, groups written additively are assumed to be [abelian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group).

But any group could just as well be $(G,\star)$ for an appropriate binary operation $\star$.

Answer (score 10):

Shaun's answer is absolutely correct: it's just a matter of notation and convention. When developing the general theory of groups, it is more common to use multiplicative notation, since additive notation is conventially reserved for commutative groups, and groups are not in general commutative. Multiplicative notation also has the advantage that $a\times b$ can be written simply as $ab$, and this advantage becomes more apparent when you start to consider products of three or more terms.

That being said, it's important to familiarise oneself with both notations, since two things which might *appear* very different might actually have the same meaning. For example, in a group $G$ written additively, if $n\in\mathbb N$ and $g\in G$, we write $ng$ to mean $\underbrace{g+g+\dots+g}_{\text{$n$ times}}$. If $G$ is instead written multiplicatively, then the same thing would be written as $g^n$. This means that "scalar multiplication" and "exponentiation" by natural numbers actually correspond to the same concept: repeated application of the group operation.

Finally, it's worth noting that the term "multiplicative group" has two distinct meanings. The first meaning is that it is a group which happens to be written multiplicatively, so the adjective "multiplicative" is actually describing the notation used to represent the group, rather than the group itself. The second meaning is used in ring theory: if $(R,+,\times)$ is a ring, then its *multiplicative group* is the group $(R^\times,\times)$, where $R^\times$ is the set of invertible elements of $R$. The multiplicative group of ring is also known as its *group of units* or *unit group*. By contrast, the *additive group* of a ring is the commutative group $(R,+)$. Outside of ring theory, "additive group" might instead just mean a group written using additive notation.

Answer (score 0):

For study of a group, it doesn’t matter much what symbol you use, but if there is another binary operation over the same set, as in a ring or field, you need a different symbol  symbol to represent that operation.